# Insert different text on different pages of a multi page pdf from command line

Tags: linux, pdf, command-line, ghostscript

I have a text file with multiple names in it, e.g

```
John Doe
Jane Doe
Mike Miller
...
```

and a pdf file with as many pages as names in the text file.

How can I insert/paste the first name at the first page, the second name at the second page and so on? I have to do it from the command line on a Linux server.

Answer (score 2):

This program works for me, but I have not done any great testing. I used a PDF file with 2 blank pages, and a text file with 2 lines of text. You will need to modify the InsertText procedure to move to the correct location. You will also need to modify the font selection and size (search for findfont in the program)

Here's an example usage:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite    \
   -sOutputFile=out.pdf \
   -sPDF_File=test.pdf  \
   -sText_File=test.txt \
    textinsert.ps
```

Please note that this is totally Ghostscript-specific and absolutely will NOT work on any other PostScript/PDF consumer.

```
%!PS
%% Copyright (C) Ken Sharp and Artifex Software Inc All rights reserved.
%% Permission granted to use, copy, modify and redistribute provided this
%% copyright remains intact. No warranty express or implied.
%%
%% Process a PDF file and a text file where one line of text from the text
%% file is drawn onto a page of the PDF file.
%% Redefine showpage so that we can draw the PDF page
%% without emitting it
%%s
/TextInsertDict 20 dict dup 3 1 roll def begin

/InsertText {
  %% Read a line of text from the text file
  TFile 256 string readline pop

  %% Move to the desired location and draw the text
  100 100 moveto show
} bind def

/Textpdfshowpage{
   save /PDFSave exch store
   /PDFdictstackcount countdictstack store
   /PDFexecstackcount count 2 sub store
   (before exec) VMDEBUG

   % set up color space substitution (this must be inside the page save)
   pdfshowpage_setcspacesub

  .writepdfmarks {

        % Copy the boxes.
    { /CropBox /BleedBox /TrimBox /ArtBox } {
      2 copy pget {
        % .pdfshowpage_Install transforms the user space do same here with the boxes
        oforce_elems
        2 { Page pdf_cached_PDF2PS_matrix transform 4 2 roll } repeat
        normrect_elems 4 index 5 1 roll fix_empty_rect_elems 4 array astore
        mark 3 1 roll /PAGE pdfmark
      } {
        pop
      } ifelse
    } forall

        % Copy annotations and links.
    dup /Annots knownoget {
      0 1 2 index length 1 sub
       { 1 index exch oget
         dup type /dicttype eq {
           dup /Subtype oget annottypes exch .knownget { exec } { pop } ifelse
         } {
           pop
         } ifelse
       }
      for pop
    } if

  } if      % end .writepdfmarks

        % Display the actual page contents.
   8 dict begin
   /BXlevel 0 def
   /BMClevel 0 def
   /OFFlevels 0 dict def
   /BGDefault currentblackgeneration def
   /UCRDefault currentundercolorremoval def
        %****** DOESN'T HANDLE COLOR TRANSFER YET ******
   /TRDefault currenttransfer def
  matrix currentmatrix 2 dict
  2 index /CropBox pget {
    oforce_elems normrect_elems boxrect
    4 array astore 1 index /ClipRect 3 -1 roll put
  } if
  dictbeginpage setmatrix
  /DefaultQstate qstate store

  count 1 sub /pdfemptycount exch store
        % If the page uses any transparency features, show it within
        % a transparency group.
  dup pageusestransparency dup /PDFusingtransparency exch def {
    % Show the page within a PDF 1.4 device filter.
    0 .pushpdf14devicefilter {
      /DefaultQstate qstate store       % device has changed -- reset DefaultQstate
      % If the page has a Group, enclose contents in transparency group.
      % (Adobe Tech Note 5407, sec 9.2)
      dup /Group knownoget {
        1 index /CropBox pget {
          /CropBox exch
        } {
          1 index get_media_box pop /MediaBox exch
        } ifelse
        oforce_elems normrect_elems fix_empty_rect_elems 4 array astore .beginformgroup 
        showpagecontents
        .endtransparencygroup
      } {
        showpagecontents
      } ifelse
    } stopped {
      % todo: discard
      .poppdf14devicefilter
      /DefaultQstate qstate store   % device has changed -- reset DefaultQstate
      stop
    } if .poppdf14devicefilter
    /DefaultQstate qstate store % device has changed -- reset DefaultQstate
  } {
    showpagecontents
  } ifelse
  .free_page_resources

  InsertText

  % todo: mixing drawing ops outside the device filter could cause
  % problems, for example with the pnga device.
  endpage
  end           % scratch dict
  % Some PDF files don't have matching q/Q (gsave/grestore) so we need
  % to clean up any left over dicts from the dictstack

  PDFdictstackcount //false
  { countdictstack 2 index le { exit } if
    currentdict /n known not or
    end
  } loop {
    StreamRunAborted not {
      (   **** Warning: File has unbalanced q/Q operators \(too many q's\)\n)
      pdfformaterror
    } if
  } if
  pop
  count PDFexecstackcount sub { pop } repeat
  (after exec) VMDEBUG
  Repaired      % pass Repaired state around the restore
  PDFSave restore
  /Repaired exch def
} bind def

%% Check both our arguments are defined leaves true on the
%% stack if so, false otherwise
%%
{PDF_File} stopped
{
  (No PDF_File defined\n) print
  false
}
{
  {Text_File} stopped
  {
    pop (No Text-File defined\n) print
    false
  }
  {
    pop pop true
  }ifelse
}ifelse

{

  %% First find the number of lines of text in the text file
  %%
  /TextLineCount 0 def
  Text_File (r) file dup
  {
    dup 256 string readline
    {
      pop /TextLineCount TextLineCount 1 add def
    }
    {
      pop exit
    } 
    ifelse
  } loop
  closefile

  %% First find the number of pages in the PDF file
  %%
  PDF_File (r) file
  runpdfbegin pdfpagecount TextLineCount eq {
    runpdfend true
  }
  {
    runpdfend false
  } ifelse
  exch
  closefile

  %% If the number of pages is the same as the number of lines
  %% the we process the files, otherwise warn and exiot
  %%
  {
    %% Select font and size
    %%
    /Times-Roman findfont 20 scalefont setfont

    %% Open the text file agaiin
    %%
    /TFile Text_File (r) file def

    %% Open the PDF file and begin PDF processing
    PDF_File (r) file
    runpdfbegin

    %% For each page....
    %%
    1 1 TextLineCount {
      %% draw the content of this page
      %%
      pdfgetpage dup /Page exch store
      pdfshowpage_init
      pdfshowpage_setpage
      Textpdfshowpage
    } for

    %% Terminate PDF processing
    %%
    runpdfend

    %% Close the text file
    %%
    TFile closefile
  } 
  {
    (Warning, Number of pages not equal to the number of text lines, aborting!\n) print flush
  }ifelse
}
{
  (Incorrect usage\n) print
  (Usage: \n) print
  (gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o <outputfile> -sPDF-File=<PDF file> -sText_File=<Text file> textinsert.ps\n) print
  (NB all switches are case-sensitive\n) print
} ifelse
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by programming in PostScript using Ghostscript. You would need to first find the number of pages in the PDF file or the number of lines in the text file, you might like to check these are the same.

Using the Ghostscript pdfwrite device, execute the page description from the PDF file, then read the text form the text file. Position the current point correctly on the content, select an appropriate font and size, and show the text. Then execute showpage to render the page.

You can either get one large PDF file with all the pages, or one PDF file per page.

Note this is not a task for someone unfamiliar with PostScript programming.

Comment: Thank you, but could you give me an example script for this?

I already have a pdf file with x pages and a text file with x lines. So I just need to put the n-th line of thext to the n-th page of the pdf file at position (a,b).

Comment: @user2502041: the least you could do now is accept KenS' answer with the script, plus upvote both answers  :)